# How to initialize and train an BERT model for NER in collab using data that I tagged manually

Tags: google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use BERT for Named Entity Recognition, the code is the following:

```
!pip install transformers

!pip install accelerate -U

import transformers
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer, Trainer
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of labels
labels = ['B-YEARS', 'B-QUANTITY', 'I-QUANTITY', 'B-COUNTRY', 'I-COUNTRY', 'O']

# Load the pre-trained BERT model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=len(labels))

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Create a BERT tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Tokenize the data
data["input_ids"] = list(map(lambda sentence: tokenizer(sentence, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt"), data["sentence"]))

# Create a Trainer object
trainer = Trainer(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

# Evaluate the model
model.evaluate(data["input_ids"], data["labels"])

new_text = "This is a random sentence."

# Tokenize the new text
new_data = pd.DataFrame({"sentence": [new_text]})
new_data["input_ids"] = model.tokenizer(new_data["sentence"], padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

# Predict the NER tags for the new text
tags = model.predict(new_data["input_ids"])

# Print the predicted NER tags
print(tags)
```

But the code returns an error on the line:
`trainer = Trainer(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)`
The specific error is:

```
ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`
```

but, as you can see, at the start I install accelerate, and the version is 0.20.3.

Also, I adjunt an image of the structure of my data:

[image: data_structure]

How can I solve the problem, or if there's another way of creating a BERT model in collab.

I executed the code added before. I'm trying to train a BERT model with the data that I tagged using regex, and test its effectivity in similar texts, but it returns an error that says that I have to install an library already installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a library version error, you may also try to update `transformers` library. Furthermore, you should use `AutoModelForTokenClassification` instead of `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` when you fine-tune a NER model. I suggest you to follow [Hugging Face Token Classification](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/2) guideline in order to fine-tune your NER model properly. Also, there is a more simple way of fine-tuning with a few lines of code using another library, `Simple Transformers`. For this one, you can follow the [NER Minimal Start](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/ner-minimal-start/) instructions. I hope these works for you.